# Regex for finding all javascript functions including arrow notation?

Tags: javascript, regex, profiling

I'd like to programatically find all javascript functions and add some code for profiling purposes (to count how many times they are called). Is there any existing tool or a regex to do that?

It is relatively easy to write something like:

```
function\s+\w+\(.*?\)\s*{
```

But that only begins to cover the multitude of options.

Comment: There can be newlines as well before and after `(` or `)`

Comment: With ES6, method fonctions no longer need the keyword `function`. I mean `obj={fn() {}}`. I don't think there's a way to find these with regex, you would need a Javascript parser.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried something similar and came to the result that a regex is not the weapon of choice for that.

But I would recommend you to have a look [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/) and create a Plugin for Babel. In step 3 »generation« you can probably modify all functions.

Answer (score 0):

Using Google Chrome (assuming universal compliance)...

1. Hit F12 to open developer console
2. Find the "Performance" tab and click on it.
3. Hit record or Ctrl + E to start / stop recording. Chrome will give you everything you need to know. :3

(PS. Just sell your soul to Google! ^w^)